# Can you take an arbitrary constant out of an absolute value sign?

Tags: absolute-value

Is |f(x) + C1| the same thing as |f(x)| + C2, where the C's are just arbitrary constants? In other words, can one take out the constant from an absolute value sign?

The context of this is that I'm trying to take the absolute value of an integral whose antiderivative evaluates to f(x) + C.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. Negative f(x) will give a counterexample

Comment: No, compare $y=-2$ for $f(x)$ and $C=-5$

Answer (score 0):

Set $f(x)=x,~$ $g(x)=\lvert x+C_1\rvert,~$ $h(x)=\lvert x\rvert+C_2$. Assume $g(x)=h(x)$ everywhere.

Then $g(-C_1)=0$ and $h(-C_1)=\lvert C_1 \rvert+C_2.$ Thus, $\lvert C_1 \rvert=-C_2,$ so $C_2 \leq 0$.

$g(0)=\lvert C_1 \rvert$ and $h(0)=C_2$, so $\lvert C_1 \rvert=C_2$ and $C_2 \geq 0.$ Therefore, $C_2=0$. It also means $C_1=0$ contradicting to $C_1$ being arbitrary integration constant.